# Suggestion of how to design GUI to render HTML formatted data

Tags: html

I am preparing for GMAT and hence preparing a question bank. gmatclub.com has lots of question and I was able to write a python script that got the questions and respective answers. While getting the data,I am retaining the HTML formatting as some questions will have underline and bold portion.

I want to develop a desktop application that should read the HTML data (i will use excel or access db as datasource). However I am not sure how to design GUI that will render the HTML formatted data. Any suggestions, on if I can use excel or access user form to show HTML formatted data. Otherwise, if I have to use browser, can I implement the logic without server side scripting that is can I use Javascript to access database(IE allows use of ActiveXobject, however it wont work on chrome and firefox thats what MS site says). The reason for not using server side scripting is, so that I can share the source code with my non-tech friends and they can use it without installing anything.

Comment: Rendering HTML in a desktop application is possible, but HTML is very complicated, and you don't want to write the engine yourself. You might look into using [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/), which allows you to make desktop apps using web technologies. If I'm not mistaken, Electron uses the WebKit rendering engine, so your HTML will work essentially as if it were running in Chrome or Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend making a very simple web page, all stored in a single file (no server side). If you can get all the HTML for the questions and answers using your python code, use that same code to also write the Q&A into an HTML file that looks like what I have below (I note with comments where you should be writing the Q&A).

I would recommend hard-coding the rest of the html file (i.e. the parts outside the Q&A section) into your python code so that it can print this entire file in one fell swoop. You can then just open this in your browser of choice:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var json = [
//Use Python to write in your Q&A's here
{
"question":"Do you want to take the GMAT",
"answer":"<b>Yes</b>, I do"
},
{
"question":"What is LLC?",
"answer":"Limited Liability <i>Company</i>"
},
//End Q&A section
];

function reset()
    {
    $('#next').hide();
    $('#showAns').show();
    $('#a').hide();
    ask();
    }

function showAnswer()
    {
    $('#next').show();
    $('#showAns').hide();
    $('#a').show();
    }

reset();


$('#next').click(function(){reset();});
$('#showAns').click(function(){showAnswer()});



function ask()
    {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * json.length);
    $('#q').html(json[randNum].question);
    $('#a').html(json[randNum].answer);
    }


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="q"></div>
<div id="a"></div>
<button id="showAns">Show Answer!</button>
<br>
<button id="next">Next Question</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Notes**

1) They'll need internet connection to use this, since I make a call to google's jQuery (so it's technically not one page), but you can just download jQuery and call it locally.

2) It sounds like you'll just be getting the list of questions once, so it might actually be quicker to format them in excel into the JSON format and then paste them in the code.

Comment: thanks for reminding about JSON. I agree, using JSON will be much easier and quicker.